# How to capture lambda code level error in cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup cloudwatch alarm for Lambda execution. I am able to setup ALARM and OK for Errors. But whenever there is any syntax error in my code I get INSUFFICIENT_DATA alarm.

I added my code below:

```
import json
import sys
print "Buckle your seat belt even if you are in back seat"
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
      print( "value 1 = " + event['key'])
      print( "value 2 = " + event['key2'])
      print( "value 3 = " + event['key3'])
      return event['key1']
    except Exception as e:
      print sys.exc_info()[0]
      raise
```

Test Data:

> {   "key3": "value3",   "key2": "value2",   "key1": "value1" }

Here is the error I am generating:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      6,
      "lambda_handler",
      "print( \"value 1 = \" + event['key'])"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'key'"
}
```

I can create a metric filter for KeyError and set my alarm. But I want to create one single alarm for all errors whether system level like lambda execution or code level like KeyError etc.
Can anyone please help me how to capture the syntax error or data error in one single alarm of cloudwatch?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but you are referencing a ``key`` attribute but the data has ``key1``.

Comment: Nope. I generated the error as a test case and I am trying to catch that error in cloud watch.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch the error in the logs, then you can use logger feature and do logger.debug(e) or logger.error(e), where e is the exception raised and caught. exception will be available in logs and then you will be able to setup alarm on top of that.